# pjsip connect to asterisk trouble

Tags: ios, swift, asterisk, sip, pjsip

I have added pjsip lib through cocoapods from here https://github.com/chebur/pjsip.

No I'm trying to connect to sip server using [this](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/samples/simple_pjsua.c) pjsip example.

Here is my code:

```
func startPjsip() {
    var status: pj_status_t
    // Create pjsua first
    status = pjsua_create()
    if status != Int32(PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
        pjsuaError("Error in pjsua_create()", status: status)
    }
    // Init Pjsua
    var config = pjsua_config()
    pjsua_config_default(&config)
    // on reg state
    config.cb.on_reg_state = { (accountId: pjsua_acc_id) in
        p("on_reg_state", accountId)
    }
    // Init the logging config structure
    var logConfig = pjsua_logging_config()
    pjsua_logging_config_default(&logConfig)
    logConfig.console_level = 4
    // Init the pjsua
    status = pjsua_init(&config, &logConfig, nil)
    if status != Int32(PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
        pjsuaError("Error in pjsua_init()", status: status)
    }
    // Adding UDP transport
    // Init transport config structure
    var udpTransportConfig = pjsua_transport_config()
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&udpTransportConfig)
    udpTransportConfig.port = 5060
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &udpTransportConfig, nil)
    if status != Int32(PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
        pjsuaError("Error in creating UDP transport", status: status)
    }
    // Initialization is done, now start pjsua
    status = pjsua_start()
    if status != Int32(PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
        pjsuaError("Error starting pjsua", status: status)
    }
    // Register the account on local sip server
    var accountConfig = pjsua_acc_config()
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&accountConfig)
    // username
    let username = "10001"
    let domain = "voip01.interpreters.travel"
    let userId = "sip:\(username)@\(domain)"
    accountConfig.id = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: userId), slen: pj_ssize_t(userId.characters.count))
    // uri
    var uri = "sip:\(domain)"
    accountConfig.reg_uri = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: uri), slen: pj_ssize_t(uri.characters.count))
    accountConfig.cred_count = 1
    accountConfig.cred_info.0.realm = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: "*"), slen: pj_ssize_t("*".characters.count))
    let scheme = "digest"
    accountConfig.cred_info.0.scheme = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: scheme), slen: pj_ssize_t(scheme.characters.count))
    accountConfig.cred_info.0.data_type = Int32(PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD.rawValue)
    let password = "10001"
    accountConfig.cred_info.0.data = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: password), slen: pj_ssize_t(password.characters.count))
    accountConfig.cred_info.0.username = pj_str_t(ptr: stringToPointer(string: username), slen: pj_ssize_t(username.characters.count))
    
    var accountId = pjsua_acc_id()
    status = pjsua_acc_add(&accountConfig, pj_bool_t(PJ_TRUE.rawValue), &accountId)
    p(accountId)
    if status != Int32(PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
        pjsuaError("Error adding account", status: status)
    }
}

func pjsuaError(_ message: String, status: pj_status_t) {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
    let fileName: String = url.lastPathComponent == nil ? #file : url.lastPathComponent!
    pjsua_perror(fileName, message, status)
    pjsua_destroy()
}

func stringToPointer(string: String) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> {
    let cs = (string as NSString).utf8String
    return UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: cs!)
}
```

When I run application I've got request sending to sip server, it returns 401 Unauthorized [(log is here)](https://pastebin.com/v6Yu6Uw4), which seems to be fine according to this [doc.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3665#section-2.1)
After that pjsip send another request and sip server return 403 Forbidden, [here is the log](https://pastebin.com/SZam5yLk).

I've asked my server guy what is the problem and he said that he used the same credentials with JsSIP lib for browser client and everything works fine for him. [Here is the log](https://pastebin.com/x9zpHQGM) he gave to me.

I have looked at his log and see difference in these lines:
mine - Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
his - Via: SIP/2.0/WSS

So seems that I'm using wrong transport protocol. But I don't know how to set pjsip to use wss protocol.

Can someone help me if you have the same issues. Or what I need to read/try to achieve my goal.

**UPDATE:**

I have added [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream), and got it working to connect to wss:// url. Here is the code:

```
var socket: WebSocket!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "wss://voip01.interpreters.travel:4443")!)
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.pongDelegate = self
    socket.headers["Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"] = "sip"
    socket.connect()
}

func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
    print("websocketDidConnect")
    print(socket)
}
```

It says "websocketDidConnect". But now I need to send `SIP REGISTER` through this `wss` transport protocol. I can't find any information how to setup pjsip to use `wss`.
I have tried to change `pjsua_transport_create` with `PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP` or `TLS` but no success.

Please, can someone help me where to find information about pjsip + websocket support.

Comment: Debug is offtopic here. There are no way answer this question without step-by-step debug. There are also difference in md5sum which you can't spot in packet

Comment: @arheops Can you advice me something to start from to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check username, check password. If not help, read SIP RFC and start debug sip stack/your code.

Comment: It's unlikely that the server will reject credentials because they come over UDP instead of web sockets, but it is possible. Have your server confirm that the user isn't limited to a certain protocol. Seems everyone is use web sockets these days, so there shouldn't be too much trouble finding resources on how to configure PJSIP to use them. BTW you should tag the question with the language you're using.

Comment: @miken32 My server guy told me that REGISTER should be send via SIP/WSS. I've added websocket lib as described in my updated answer but I've searched a lot but didn't find anything about connection pjsip and websocket in ios together. Can you help me with some documentation etc? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: PJSUA API doesn't support WSS for transport. You have to ask your server administrator to enable TCP/UDP for you.

Comment: @JohnTracid Yes, I've already asked him to configure tcp transport protocol for me. Now it works fine, thanks.